# create a new variable and compute row and column in R

Tags: r

I would like to calculate column sum based on a given list of state. For example, I have 3 columns and 3 rows. I would like to calculate total work done by the state in a separate column.

```
client   state   work done
 john      FL       10
 Max       WA       15
 Roy       GA       21
 Stacy     FL       9
 clara     WA       10
```

I would like to create a new variable like sum of work done by state. example

```
client    state   workdone   state workdone 2
 John      FL        10       FL     19
 Max       WA        15       WA     25
 Roy       GA        21       GA     21
 stacy     FL        9
 Clara     WA        10
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to summarise as a new dataset? i.e. `aggregate(workdone~state, df1, sum)`

Comment: if i have multiple rows then how to create a new data set by state? like work done, pending, new work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
data2 = data %>% group_by(state) %>% summarize(workdone2 = sum(workdone))
```

Comment: if i have multiple rows then how to create a new data set by state? like work done, pending, new work

Comment: data2 refers to your new dataset by state